# Adding attributes to existing json payload using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am getting json response as below. I want to add "**

**schemas":[
"urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User",           "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User"
],
"id":"xyz",**

**
to each resource how to do this using javascript. Can anyone help.

```
{
    "Resources": [
        {
            "emails": {
                "type": "bobsmith01@company.com",
                "value": "Personal"
            },
            "name": {
                "familyName": "Bob-update3",
                "givenName": "Smith"
            },
            "detail": "SUCCESS",
            "userName": "bobsmith01@company.com",
            "status": "200"
        },
        {
            "emails": {
                "type": "samgomes@company.com",
                "value": "Personal"
            },
            "name": {
                "familyName": "gomes",
                "givenName": "sam"
            },
            "detail": "SUCCESS",
            "userName": "samgomes@company.com",
            "status": "200"
        }
    ]
}
```

Required output is as below.

```
{
    "Resources": [
        {
        "schemas":[
            "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User",
            "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User"
         ],
         "id":"xyz",
            "emails": {
                "type": "bobsmith01@company.com",
                "value": "Personal"
            },
            "name": {
                "familyName": "Bob-update3",
                "givenName": "Smith"
            },
            "detail": "SUCCESS",
            "userName": "bobsmith01@company.com",
            "status": "200"
        }
        {
        "schemas":[
            "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User",
            "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User"
         ],
         "id":"abc",
            "emails": {
                "type": "samgomes@company.com",
                "value": "Personal"
            },
            "name": {
                "familyName": "gomes",
                "givenName": "sam"
            },
            "detail": "SUCCESS",
            "userName": "samgomes@company.com",
            "status": "200"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Parse the data, use `Array.prototype.map` to modify each element and serialize the object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6 JS spread operator (...) and Array.map to achieve this:

```js
const orgObject = {
    "Resources": [{
            "emails": {
                "type": "bobsmith01@company.com",
                "value": "Personal"
            },
            "name": {
                "familyName": "Bob-update3",
                "givenName": "Smith"
            },
            "detail": "SUCCESS",
            "userName": "bobsmith01@company.com",
            "status": "200"
        },
        {
            "emails": {
                "type": "samgomes@company.com",
                "value": "Personal"
            },
            "name": {
                "familyName": "gomes",
                "givenName": "sam"
            },
            "detail": "SUCCESS",
            "userName": "samgomes@company.com",
            "status": "200"
        }
    ]
}


const copiedObject = {...orgObject};   // Copy object to avoid mutation preferably use lodash.cloneDeep 
// loop through the object.Resources using map
copiedObject.Resources = copiedObject.Resources.map(res => { 
    return {
        "schemas": [
            "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User",
            "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User"
        ],
        "id": "xyz",
        ...res  // Use spread operator to copy the existing object properties from Resources 
    }
});
console.log(copiedObject)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{
  top:0;
  max-height:100% !important;
}
```